# CAGradientLayer radial gradient

Tags: objective-c, uiview, cagradientlayer

I used the following code to set gradient color:

```
NSArray *locations = @[@0.0, @0.1f];

CAGradientLayer *headerLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
headerLayer.colors = colors;
headerLayer.locations = locations;
```

How can I make radial gradient color?

I think I have to change locations, but I didn't guess the correct locations. Also, I tried this:

```
headerLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Update:**

Seems like it does, other answers show the method.

---

Unfortunately, `CAGradientLayer` doesn't support radial gradients. The only way to do that is to subclass `CALayer` and do the drawing yourself.

I have answered the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26924839/456434), but since this is an older question, the other one might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 17):

By 2019, the accepted answer is erroneous and you can make a radial gradient by setting its type property to .radial.
On thing important is that the startPoint is the coordinate of the center of the ellipse or circle and the endPoint  are the dimensions of the outer eclipse or circle. All coordinates have to be expressed in unit-based (aka 1.0 is 100%).

The following Swift example will draw an ellipse positioned at the center  of the frame and the radiuses set to match the frame:

```
    let g = CAGradientLayer()

    // We want a radial gradient
    g.type = .radial

    g.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]

    let center = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)        
    g.startPoint = center

    let radius = 1.5
    g.endPoint = CGPoint(x: radius, y: radius)
```

The above example can be used to add a vignette to a view for example (see the image).

Note that the radius can be larger than the frame, and the center can be placed outside the frame as well by specifying coordinates greater than 1 or lower than -1.

[image]

Comment: Whenever I try to do this, I get a very "striped" weird looking gradient on runtime with the simulator. When I took a snapshot test, however, on the snapshot it looked fine. :(

Comment: It seems like I cannot paste my code here :( the code is too long according to stack overflow :( I'm creating a stack overflow question right now, I will paste the link here when I publish it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889427/radial-cagradientlayer-not-rendering-properly-at-runtime

Comment: The word "radius" is not accurate in this example. If we want the code to truly treat that as a radius, the last line needs to be replaced with:
`let edgeLen =  sqrt((radius*radius)/2.0);
g.endPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + edgeLen, y: center.y + edgeLen)`

Answer (score 1):

you can't init radial CAGradientLayer, BUT you can easily modify current layer style to radial

```
layer.type = .radial
```